# Back to site option not available

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

Solution for back to site button customization is mentioned as following in the [online documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html).

```
 var options = new DashboardOptions { 
        AppPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~") 
    };

    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
```

I am using following set up

```
app.UseHangfire(
    config => {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionString");
        config.UseDashboardPath("/myscheduler");
    }
);
```

Amazingly `app.UseHangfireDashboard("");` as mentioned in the online documentation was not available in my project.That is why I am using `app.UseHangfire("");` setup

How to set the back to site option in case of sub-folder deployment?

Comment: Have you got a `using Hangfire;` statement in there?

Comment: @DavidG ofcouse Please note that every thing is working for me except back to site button at the top right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the version older version , It was solved by updating to latest version 1.5.3.